# Print more than one page with Printable on Java

Tags: java, eclipse, printing

I need to print more than one page on my application, but when I try to print it I get only one page printed, or the same page printed 5 times, for example.

I put the code below:

```
MyPrintableTable mpt = new MyPrintableTable();
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
//PageFormat pf = job.defaultPage();
job.setPrintable(mpt);             
job.printDialog();             
try 
{
    job.print();
} 
catch (PrinterException e) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

"MyPrintableTable" class:

```
class MyPrintableTable implements Printable 
{
    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int pageIndex) 
    {
        if (pageIndex != 0)
           return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        g2.setPaint(Color.black);
        int x = 100;
        int y = 100;
        for(int i = 0; i < sTable.size(); i++)
        {
            g2.drawString(sTable.get(i).toString(), x, y);
            y += 20;                    
        }
        return PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
}
```

If I change the "pageIndex !=0" condition, I have more pages printed, but all with the same text.

I want to print all my text, that has a three page lenght, but I only can print the first one, o print three times the first one.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Why don't you use `pageIndex` to select the data to print? See [Printing a Multiple Page Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/set.html)

Comment: I see that two hours before, but I don't know how to use it on my code, can you help me?

Comment: You need to work out which data belongs on which page, and modify your for-loop accordingly. Perhaps something like `for(int i = pageIndex * linesPerPage; i < sTable.size() && i < (pageIndex+1)*linesPerPage; i++)`, where `linesPerPage` is the number of table entries you plan to show on each page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a test program that demonstrates the principles I previously suggested in comments. It is based on ideas from [Printing a Multiple Page Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/set.html), as well as on the code in the question. In a real program I would probably calculate `linesPerPage` rather than compiling in a number.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyPrintableTable mpt = new MyPrintableTable();
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    // PageFormat pf = job.defaultPage();
    job.setPrintable(mpt);
    job.printDialog();
    try {
      job.print();
    } catch (PrinterException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}

class MyPrintableTable implements Printable {
  private int linesPerPage = 20;
  private List<String> sTable = new ArrayList<String>();
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      sTable.add("Line" + i);
    }
  }

  public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int pageIndex) {
    if (pageIndex * linesPerPage >= sTable.size())
      return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    g2.setPaint(Color.black);
    int x = 100;
    int y = 100;
    for (int i = linesPerPage * pageIndex; i < sTable.size()
        && i < linesPerPage * (pageIndex + 1); i++) {
      g2.drawString(sTable.get(i).toString(), x, y);
      y += 20;
    }
    return PAGE_EXISTS;
  }
}
```