# Java Printable not printing multiple pages

Tags: printing, graphics2d

My print function could only print one page so I tried changing it to print multiple pages. I have now changed my code to print two pages. But the second page is always a blank page.

So on one page there can be 27 "tasks" printed. There are 3 lines each page and each line containing 9 tasks. I have tried changing the if statement in order to get it to print a second page but couldn't get it to work.

```
if ((i < 9) || ((i>=3*9) && (i<4*9)))

else if ((i < 2*9) || ((i>=4*9) && (i<5*9)))

else if ((i < 3*9) || ((i>=5*9) && (i<6*9))){
```

Example Code (excuse the poorly written code):

```
public class Printer implements Printable {
private ArrayList<Task> dataTasks;
private ArrayList<Tag> dataTags;
private int tasksPerPage = 27;

public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {

    if (pageIndex * tasksPerPage >= dataTasks.size()) {
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

    Font titleFont = new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 12);
    g2d.setFont(titleFont);

    for (int i = tasksPerPage * pageIndex; i < dataTasks.size() && i < tasksPerPage * (pageIndex + 1); i++){
        if ((i < 9) || ((i>=3*9) && (i<4*9))){
            g.drawString("Task:     " + dataTasks.get(i).getName(), 10, 10 + i * 90);
            g.drawString("Created:  " + dataTasks.get(i).getCreationDate().toString(true,false), 10, 22 + i * 90);
            g.drawString("Deadline: " + dataTasks.get(i).getDeadline().toString(true,true), 10, 34 + i * 90);
            g.drawString("Compl.:   " + dataTasks.get(i).getCompletionDate().toString(true,true),10,46+i*90);

            if (dataTasks.get(i).gettagIdList().size() == 0){
                g.drawString("Tags:     ", 10, 46 + i * 90);
            } else {
                for (int j = 0; j < dataTasks.get(i).gettagIdList().size(); j++) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < dataTags.size(); k++) {
                        if (dataTasks.get(i).gettagIdList().get(j) == dataTags.get(k).getId()){
                            if (j == 0){
                                g.drawString("Tags:     " + dataTags.get(k).getName(), 10, 58 + i * 90);
                            } else {
                                g.drawString("          " + dataTags.get(k).getName(), 10, 58 + i * 90  + j * 10);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } else if ((i < 2*9) || ((i>=4*9) && (i<5*9))){
            int move1 = 202;
            g.drawString("Task:     " + dataTasks.get(i).getName(), move1, 10 + (i-9) * 90);
            g.drawString("Created:  " + dataTasks.get(i).getCreationDate().toString(true,false), move1, 22 + (i-9) * 90);
            g.drawString("Deadline: " + dataTasks.get(i).getDeadline().toString(true,true), move1, 34 + (i-9) * 90);
            g.drawString("Compl.:   "+dataTasks.get(i).getCompletionDate().toString(true,true),move1,46+(i-9)*90);

            if (dataTasks.get(i).gettagIdList().size() == 0){
                g.drawString("Tags:     ", move1, 46 + (i-9) * 90);
            } else {
                for (int j = 0; j < dataTasks.get(i).gettagIdList().size(); j++) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < dataTags.size(); k++) {
                        if (dataTasks.get(i).gettagIdList().get(j) == dataTags.get(k).getId()){
                            if (j == 0){
                                g.drawString("Tags:     " + dataTags.get(k).getName(), move1, 58 + (i-9) * 90);
                            } else {
                                g.drawString("          " + dataTags.get(k).getName(), move1, 58 + (i-9) * 90  + j * 10);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if ((i < 3*9) || ((i>=5*9) && (i<6*9))){
            int move2y = 392;
            int move2x = (i-18) * 90;
            g.drawString("Task:     " + dataTasks.get(i).getName(), move2y, 10 + move2x);
            g.drawString("Created:  " + dataTasks.get(i).getCreationDate().toString(true,false), move2y, 22 + move2x);
            g.drawString("Deadline: " + dataTasks.get(i).getDeadline().toString(true,true), move2y, 34 + move2x);
            g.drawString("Compl.:   "+dataTasks.get(i).getCompletionDate().toString(true,true),move2y,46+move2x);

            if (dataTasks.get(i).gettagIdList().size() == 0){
                g.drawString("Tags:     ", move2y, 46 + move2x);
            } else {
                for (int j = 0; j < dataTasks.get(i).gettagIdList().size(); j++) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < dataTags.size(); k++) {
                        if (dataTasks.get(i).gettagIdList().get(j) == dataTags.get(k).getId()){
                            if (j == 0){
                                g.drawString("Tags:     " + dataTags.get(k).getName(), move2y, 58 + move2x);
                            } else {
                                g.drawString("          " + dataTags.get(k).getName(), move2y, 58 + move2x + j * 10);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    return PAGE_EXISTS;
}
```

I have tried doing it as the following post: [Print more than one page with Printable on Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152261/print-more-than-one-page-with-printable-on-java)